# Exception thrown during try-with-resources declaration

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Say I have the following try-with-resources statement in Java:

```
try (MyResource myResource1 = new MyResource(); MyResource myResource2 = new MyResource()) {
    // do stuff...
}
```

If `MyResource myResource2 = new MyResource()` throws an exception, is it guaranteed that `myResource1.close()` will be called?

Comment: Yes it's same as finally as long as resources implements java.lang.AutoCloseable

Comment: yes but the resource must implement AutoClosable

Comment: @Tunaki - it compiles in java 8

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, this is guaranteed. Quoting from [JLS section 14.20.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

> Resources are initialized in left-to-right order. **If a resource fails to initialize (that is, its initializer expression throws an exception), then all resources initialized so far by the try-with-resources statement are closed**. If all resources initialize successfully, the try block executes as normal and then all non-null resources of the try-with-resources statement are closed.

In this case, if the second `new MyResource()` throws an exception, since `myResource1` was successfully initialized, it will be closed.

Comment: If the exception is thrown inside try-with-resources declaration then will the try block statements get executed or the control goes to catch block?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily try it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Resource1 myResource1 = new Resource1(); Resource2 myResource2 = new Resource2()) {
        // do stuff...
    }
}


class Resource1 implements AutoCloseable {

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Closing Resource1...");
    }

}

class Resource2 implements AutoCloseable {

    public Resource2() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Bad resource!");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Closing Resource2...");
    }

}
```

**Output:**

> Closing Resource1...
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad resource!

which shows the first resource is closed.

Comment: I edited it to construct objects.  The point is just whether exceptions thrown during the try declaration, between the parentheses, will be caught, or if it's only exceptions between the curly braces that will be caught.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is "is it guaranteed?". This answers that for your particular JDK, for this specific execution, it worked.

Comment: @Tunaki It does answer the question. I just opted to show it via a simple example instead of quoting the spec.

Comment: The example does not guarantee that it is true, is what I'm saying. You would need to test your example on all version across all possible JDK implementation.

Comment: Nicely Explained